# Object reference not set to an instance of an object button press event

Tags: c#, winsockets

I'm getting an error message and I don't know how to fix it. This is the original code I have:

```
private void SendMessage(Command cmd, EndPoint sendToEP)
{
    try
    {
        //Create the message to send.
        Data msgToSend = new Data();

        //msgToSend.strName = txtName.Text;   //Name of the user.
        msgToSend.cmdCommand = cmd;         //Message to send.
        msgToSend.vocoder = vocoder;        //Vocoder to be used.

        byte[] message = msgToSend.ToByte();

        //Send the message asynchronously.
        clientSocket.BeginSendTo(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, sendToEP, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "UniProject-SendMessage ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The error message is (button press event)

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why am I getting this error message and how can i fix it?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: The only thing in that code snippet that could cause the `NullReferenceException` is `clientSocket` being null. You need to spend some time learning how to debug your code.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you get such an error (a `NullReferenceException`), there is something in your code that is set to `null`. You have to look at your code and determine:

1. On which line (in which method) does the error occur?
2. What variables on that line are *reference types* or *nullable value types*?
   Normal value types (e.g. `struct`, or integers, floats, doubles) cannot be `null`.
3. Of those variables, which could *possibly* be `null`?
4. Where are those variables possibly set to `null`?
   For example, a method argument, a value returned from a method, or the result of the `as` operator can result in a variable being `null`.

If none of those is the case, you might have (although unlikely) a method that is throwing this exception. The .NET base class methods generally don't throw such an exception, and if your code does throw it, your stack trace should bring you to the deepest method and line that does that.

Comment: With the exception of nullable value types of course, which are still value types

Comment: @DavidL Nice catch. Nullable types are actually kind of _in-between_ reference types and value types, and I forgot about them. For example, you can constrain a generic type to `class` for reference types, or `struct` for _non-nullable_ value types. Nullable value types are special.

Comment: I agree with Virtlink that values types are quite special.  On *no other value type* can you get a `NullReferenceException` when using dot notation against the boxed representation of that value type.  That's pretty special to me.

Comment: @Virtlink, what's an example where you can get the NRE with any other boxed value type?

Comment: @KirkWoll Ah I see what you mean, I misunderstood you. There is _no_ non-nullable value type that, when boxed, will returned in a `NullReferenceException`.